# open method or function with window.open

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have a simple app which open a website in a webview. But I have the problem. there is a litte dropdown many and one of the hyperlink open a new tab with javascript (the safari developer mode told me it's an event listener) `window.open('$var', '_blank')` and this doesn't work. (the app crashed) The original html href works fine. Is it possible, if a user clicks on the javalink to open a function in the android app like the share/publish function.

I already added

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

I hope someone can help me

This is the Log when the app crash

```
11-27 16:13:31.995 13687-13687/? E/SMD: smd Interface open failed errno is 2 -1
11-27 16:13:33.106 889-1182/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.1580 ] when=180451552041000
11-27 16:13:33.106 889-1181/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (1269): action: 0x4, toolType: 1
11-27 16:13:33.106 889-1181/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (11174): action: 0x0, toolType: 1
11-27 16:13:33.266 889-1182/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=180451718423000
11-27 16:13:33.266 889-1181/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (11174): action: 0x1, toolType: 1
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:471)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:461)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:433)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at com.myapp.MainActivity$2.onCreateWindow(MainActivity.java:252)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onCreateWindow(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:140)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter.addNewContents(AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter.java:72)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:9)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
11-27 16:13:33.326 11174-11174/com.myapp A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(243)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
11-27 16:13:33.486 14967-14967/? A/google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
11-27 16:13:33.486 14967-14967/? A/google-breakpad: V AndroidWebView:62.0.3202.84
11-27 16:13:33.486 14967-14967/? A/google-breakpad: O A arm 04 armv7l samsung/jfltexx/jflte:5.0.1/LRX22C/I9505XXUHPK2:user/release-keys
11-27 16:13:33.486 14967-14967/? A/google-breakpad: P webview
11-27 16:13:33.486 14967-14967/? A/google-breakpad: R 00000006 SIGABRT 00002BA6
11-27 16:13:33.486 14967-14967/? A/google-breakpad: G 
.......
11-27 16:13:33.516 14967-14967/? A/google-breakpad: M B6F10000 00000000 0000D000 19F4E4792C30C35C68ADF49F4CAC547C0 linker
11-27 16:13:33.516 14967-14967/? A/google-breakpad: -----END BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
11-27 16:13:33.566 11174-11174/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
11-27 16:13:33.566 11174-11174/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
11-27 16:13:33.566 11174-11174/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: 1.0.7
11-27 16:13:33.566 11174-11174/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: 10007
11-27 16:13:33.566 11174-11174/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
11-27 16:13:33.566 11174-11174/com.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 11174 (com.myapp)
11-27 16:13:33.586 11174-11181/com.myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.615ms
11-27 16:13:33.626 11174-11187/com.myapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 100997(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 23(558KB) LOS objects, 23% free, 19MB/25MB, paused 2.685ms total 294.189ms
11-27 16:13:33.676 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-27 16:13:33.676 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/jfltexx/jflte:5.0.1/LRX22C/I9505XXUHPK2:user/release-keys'
11-27 16:13:33.676 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '11'
11-27 16:13:33.676 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
11-27 16:13:33.676 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG: pid: 11174, tid: 11174, name: com.myapp  >>> com.myapp <<<
11-27 16:13:33.676 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG: Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(243)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
                                          '
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00002ba6  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG:     r4 b6f1f114  r5 00000006  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG:     r8 0000004f  r9 00000000  sl 00000000  fp be965b24
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG:     ip 00002ba6  sp be965558  lr b6ea8fbd  pc b6ecc1e4  cpsr 600b0010
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000371e4  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00013fb9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00014bd7  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00011519  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000fca4  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
11-27 16:13:33.706 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 002a5cfd  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so
11-27 16:13:35.498 20116-20116/? I/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01


                                          [ 11-27 16:13:35.498 20116:20116 E/         ]
                                          ro.product_ship = true

                                          [ 11-27 16:13:35.498 20116:20116 E/         ]
                                          ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
11-27 16:13:35.498 889-1025/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
11-27 16:13:35.498 889-3339/? E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
11-27 16:13:35.508 889-15005/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.myapp/.MainActivity
11-27 16:13:35.508 1951-1951/? E/audit: type=1701 msg=audit(1511795615.508:6249): auid=4294967295 uid=10244 gid=10244 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 pid=11174 comm="com.myapp" reason="memory violation" sig=6
11-27 16:13:35.578 889-4109/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{d0ba068 u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity}
11-27 16:13:35.588 889-1210/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=332, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
11-27 16:13:35.588 889-1210/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=331, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
11-27 16:13:35.638 889-15005/? W/ActivityManager: Exception thrown during pause
                                                  android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                                                      at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:766)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:1186)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3661)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3475)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:3410)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:14695)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:14568)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:15334)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:14842)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
11-27 16:13:35.648 889-15005/? W/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire()
11-27 16:13:35.648 275-275/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/11174/oom_score_adj; errno=22
11-27 16:13:35.658 889-1163/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.myapp (pid 11174)(adj 1) has died(246,275)
11-27 16:13:35.688 15017-15017/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
11-27 16:13:35.688 889-15018/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
11-27 16:13:35.688 889-15018/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
11-27 16:13:35.698 316-316/? I/Zygote: Process 11174 exited due to signal (6)
11-27 16:13:35.708 889-4104/? I/WallpaperManagerService: switchPersonaWallpaper is called for personaId-0
11-27 16:13:35.708 11239-11239/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:2064 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:533 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:533 com.samsung.android.sm.common.SmartManagerReceiver.b:199 com.samsung.android.sm.common.SmartManagerReceiver.onReceive:93 
11-27 16:13:35.718 889-889/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1713 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.broadcastEvent:296 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.processDropBoxEntry:254 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.access$100:60 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector$1.onReceive:102 
11-27 16:13:35.728 889-1238/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-27 16:13:35.838 1534-1534/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2151ee8 time:180454286
11-27 16:13:35.878 889-1762/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.sec.android.intent.action.HOME_RESUME flg=0x10 } from com.sec.android.app.launcher (pid=1534, uid=10024) is not exported from uid 10156 due to receiver com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock2x1/.DigitalClockWidgetProvider
11-27 16:13:35.888 889-910/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{d0ba068 u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} couldn't find taskId=898 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.computeFrameLw:1054 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.layoutWindowLw:4904 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutLockedInner:10917 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:11857 
11-27 16:13:35.888 889-1030/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{d0ba068 u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} couldn't find taskId=898 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.computeFrameLw:1054 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.layoutWindowLw:4904 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutLockedInner:10917 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:11857 
11-27 16:13:36.109 889-1030/? W/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.release()
11-27 16:13:36.109 889-1030/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{3ae7cee7 u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher t769} time:180454556
11-27 16:13:36.109 889-1030/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{d0ba068 u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} couldn't find taskId=898 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.computeFrameLw:1054 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.layoutWindowLw:4904 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutLockedInner:10917 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:11857 
11-27 16:13:36.119 889-1030/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{d0ba068 u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} couldn't find taskId=898 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.computeFrameLw:1054 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.layoutWindowLw:4904 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutLockedInner:10917 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:11857 
11-27 16:13:36.139 889-1030/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{d0ba068 u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} couldn't find taskId=898 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.computeFrameLw:1054 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.layoutWindowLw:4904 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutLockedInner:10917 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:11857 
11-27 16:13:36.229 889-902/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 124316(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 96(3MB) LOS objects, 12% free, 54MB/62MB, paused 2.838ms total 113.342ms
11-27 16:13:36.779 889-889/? I/MotionRecognitionService: Plugged
11-27 16:13:36.779 889-889/? I/MotionRecognitionService: setPowerConnected  = true
11-27 16:13:37.750 889-1182/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.1581 ] when=180456207742000
11-27 16:13:37.760 889-1181/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (1269): action: 0x4, toolType: 1
11-27 16:13:37.760 889-1181/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (889): action: 0x0, toolType: 1
11-27 16:13:37.860 889-1182/? I/InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=180456309579000
11-27 16:13:37.860 889-1181/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (889): action: 0x1, toolType: 1
11-27 16:13:37.860 304-12987/? I/AudioPolicyManager_legacy: getAudioPolicyConfig: situation=1;device=0
11-27 16:13:37.860 304-12987/? I/AudioPolicyManager_legacy: getSituationVolume: isBTConnected:0 isHeadConnected:0
11-27 16:13:37.870 889-1218/? E/AudioTrack: AudioTrack::set : Exit
11-27 16:13:37.880 304-787/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -8
11-27 16:13:37.920 889-1010/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{d0ba068 u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} couldn't find taskId=898 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.computeFrameLw:1054 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.layoutWindowLw:4904 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutLockedInner:10917 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:11857 
11-27 16:13:37.930 889-1333/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 11174 uid 10244
11-27 16:13:37.940 889-1010/? E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
11-27 16:13:37.950 889-4104/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{d0ba068 u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} couldn't find taskId=898 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.computeFrameLw:1054 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.layoutWindowLw:4904 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutLockedInner:10917 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:11857 
11-27 16:13:37.950 889-15051/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1699 com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService$6.run:2733 java.lang.Thread.run:818 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> 
11-27 16:13:37.950 889-1238/? E/OpenGLRenderer: SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
11-27 16:13:38.120 889-1030/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{d0ba068 u0 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} couldn't find taskId=898 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.computeFrameLw:1054 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.layoutWindowLw:4904 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutLockedInner:10917 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:11857
```

Comment: What is `$var`? What does that do?

Comment: $var is the link '/folder/ + $id'

Comment: Can you give an example of log of $var?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `window.open('YOUR PAGE NAME', '_self', false);`
I have used it myself. It strange that your app crashes to open a new html link.

For more [info](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) about `window.open`

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i found out: I have a onCreateWindow method which open the Url in a new activity. and i handover the url with result.getdata()
If i click on the href the log shows the right link!. If I click on the "javalink" the log is empty?!

can someone tell me why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B34om.jpg)

```
  public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, android.os.Message resultMsg) {
            WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
            String data = result.getExtra();
            Log.d("url", data);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a new Activity? Just edit your post instead of adding an answer. What is the var `parent[1]`

Comment: the var parent[1] is the userid. It can be 1 or 5 or 34894793485. I want to create a new activity because I have some options and buttons in this Activity.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between this `If i click on the href the log shows the right link!. If I click on the "javalink" the log is empty?!` Do you mean it log right in the JS but not in the android native?